# How to compare (in a shell script) two files by basename then discard one?

Tags: macos, bash, perl, shell

I'm using the bash shell on OS X (10.7). I have quite a few directories of audio files like so:

```
dir/audio.mp3
dir/audio.m4a
```

I'd like to programmatically discard one of the files, but how? I know how to get the base names:

```
find . -type f -exec basename -a {} + | sort | awk -F"." '{print $1}' | uniq -d
```

But I'm stumped how to 'tag' the mp3s, say, so that `rm` can do its thing. Ideally I would keep the highest bitrate files, but for now cutting by file extensions will do.

Perhaps Perl is the better tool, but I'm not proficient enough with Perl to begin tackling this.

Comment: `basename` only takes one file at a time.  Which file do you want to discard?  Is it always the `.mp3` when both the `.mp3` and `.m4a` exist?  Presumably, if only one of the two possible files with the same basename exists, then you want to keep it.

Comment: I would construct something like `find . -type f -name '*.m4a' | xargs script2delete_mp3_IfExists`. Where `script2delete...` just outputs text strings like `rm dir/audio.mp3`, which you can look at before executing. When all the output looks good, then you can pipe that like `find ... | xargs ... | /bin/bash` and the shell will then execute the commands passed thru the pipe. YOu can then make `script2delete..` as smart as you want, if it finds mp3, it can confirm the `..m4a` has the higher bitrate but if not, output would be `rm dir/audio.m4a`. Good luck.

Comment: Jonathan, yes I would like always to discard the `.mp3` version, but only if the basename is duplicated with another extension. I also have a few `.flac` files which would take precedence.

Comment: Thanks, shellter. Piping to the shell is new to me; I'll have to investigate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Perl, what you would be wanting is the `File::Find` module.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my $search_path = "dir/";

my %exists;

sub find_dupes {
    my $filename = $_;
    $filename =~ s/\.\w+$//;    #remove extension)
    if ( $exists{$filename} ) {
        print $File::Find::name, " may be a duplicate of ",
            $exists{$filename}, "($filename)\n";

        ##maybe delete the duplicate via unlink();
    }
    else {
        $exists{$filename} = $File::Find::name;
    }
}

find( \&find_dupes, $search_path );
```

NB: Doesn't actually do the deletion. That's left for you. You can probably use `File::Find` to do more clever comparisons such as modification time, filesize. You may even find you can extract MP3 metadata automatically, with a module like [`MP3::Info`](http://search.cpan.org/~cnandor/MP3-Info/Info.pm). I've not used that one, so YMMV.

Comment: Thanks, Sobrique. This is clear to me, even with my rudimentary Perl skills.

Comment: Just because perl has a bad reputation for being ugly spaghetti code, that doesn't mean you _have_ to follow the trend :)

Comment: :) Cool to know about `MP3::Info` as well

Answer (score 1):

You can get the basename of a file using the `basename` command (looks like you're doing this step from `find` anyways...):

```
$ file="/foo/bar/baz.ext"
$ echo $file
/foo/bar/baz.ext

$ name="$(basename "$file")"
$ echo $name
baz.ext
```

Then to remove the extension, use the `%.*` *Parameter Expansion* to strip out the last dot and everything that follows:

```
$ base="${name%.*}"
$ echo $base
baz
```

`man bash`, search for "Parameter Expansion" for more info. This works in ksh/zsh too.

Comment: Parameter expansion, I keep forgetting about this. Thanks.

Comment: Also I think `base="${base%.*}"` should be `base="${name%.*}"` here.

Comment: @sqldoug that's correct, I changed the name to add $base and forgot that one. Corrected.